AWS Lambda & google-ads 25
just wondering if someone can help me with this issue:
I am trying to run a code in a lambda function and I have created a layer for this using a docker to create the needed libs:
# Use an official Amazon w/python3
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
# Create and activate a virtual environment
RUN python3.9 -m venv /app/venv
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Install required packages
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages --python-version 3.9 --only-binary=:all:  -r requirements.txt

when i upload the function code and test it i am receiving this error:
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'google_conversion_lambda': google-ads
Traceback (most recent call last):INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3853.19 ms Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'google_conversion_lambda': google-ads
Traceback (most recent call last):INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 25715.69 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

the import is coded like this:
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

its is weird and I am running out of ideas to try. Any suggestions or other leads that I can try?
I already tried:

On the code Zip file include all the google libraries needed along with the function.
Rebuilding as a layer, with other building methods using the docker.

Both shows the same results.
EDIT:
Just to let you know the issue here is that I was zipping the files on a windows environment and even the zipping process should happen inside the docker environment (Linux) after that we are good to export the zip file and update the layer.
